# Excel VBA automation error with new application object

Tags: excel, vba, object, automation

I have had a complex project work just fine for many years.

However recently I have started getting the following runtime error:

> Microsoft Visual Basic
>
> Run-time error '-2147319765 (8002802b)':
>
> Automation error Element not found

I have boiled this down to the simplest possible sub, as follows:

```
Sub test()
    Dim xl As Excel.Application
    Set xl = New Excel.Application ' the error occurs on this line
End Sub
```

References are as per the standard installation. For some reason the system doesn't allow me to add a screenshot. This is now with VBA version 7.1 - I don't know if that makes any difference. This is a corporate environment, with many limitation on what staff can do: so I'm unable to install a new .ddl etc.

Comment: Does the code run from a different Office application (Word, Powerpoint...)? Else I see no point in opening a new application object.

Comment: @FunThomas - as stated, the above code is the simplest possible example to demonstrate the error. The real thing is a whole lot more complex. And yes, a new Application object is definitely needed.

Comment: Do you have any code that is executed automatically when Excel is opened (eg via AddIn?)

Comment: @FunThomas - nope.

Comment: Try `Dim xl as Object` and `Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application." & CLng(Application.Version))` The number at the end is the version of excel you have installed and want to open. 11 is Excel 2003, 12 is Excel 2007 and 16 is the recent stuff.

Comment: Is the file .xls or .xlsm?  Do you have any ActiveX controls in the document?

Comment: @Toddleson - YES, thank you. This fixed the problem. If you want to post this as a full answer, and not just a comment, I'll happily give you a green tick.

Comment: That is good to hear. And I have posted it as an answer instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```vb
Dim xl as Object 
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application." & CLng(Application.Version))
```

This is just an alternate method of opening a new Excel application but it fixes the issue of a user having multiple versions of Excel installed by specifically calling out the version you want to open.

It would usually be written like "Excel.Application.12" where number at the end is the version of excel you have installed and want to open. 11 is Excel 2003, 12 is Excel 2007 and 16 is the recent stuff.

I replaced that number with `Application.Version` to say open the version you already are using.